# stack in c with linked list - comparing an element with element in head error

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement an application that uses a stack of `employee` structures using a single-link list, where each employee is described by his / her VAT number, name and salary.

I am trying extend the code so that when the user selects "1" it will read the data of the new employee from the console, check if his salary is higher than the salary of the employee at the top of the stack, and print the result of the comparison.

The push of new elements in the stack goes fine, but the `if` that checks whether the salary is higher than the salary on top of stack does not work.

Likewise, I would like to know what to add so that the user can hit "3" to print the data of every unique employee in the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct employee {
int am;
char name[50];
float salary;
struct employee *next;
};

void init(struct employee **head);
void show(struct employee *head);
int push(struct employee s, struct employee **head);
int pop(struct employee *s, struct employee **head);

int main(){

struct employee data;
struct employee *head;
int ch;
init(&head);
do {
    printf("\nMenu ");
    printf("\n1.Push ");
    printf("\n2.Pop ");
    printf("\n3.Show contents ");
    printf("\n0.Exit ");
    printf("\nChoice: ");
    scanf("%d",&ch);

    switch (ch) {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter employee data:");
        scanf("%d %s %f", &data.am, data.name, &data.salary);
        if (push(data,&head)){
            printf("Successfully pushed to stack.\n");
            printf("%f\n", data.next->salary);
            if (data.salary > head->salary)
                 printf("salary on the head is bigger\n");
            else
                printf("salary on the head is less\n");
        }
        else
            printf("No memory available, push failed.\n");
    break;

    case 2:
        if (pop(&data,&head))
            printf("Popped: %d %s %.1f\n",data.am, data.name, data.salary);
        else
            printf("Empty stack, no data retrieved.\n");
        break;
     case 3:
        show(head);
        break;
     case 0:
        printf("Bye!\n");
        break;
    default: 
        printf("Try again.\n");
        break;
    } 
} while (ch!=0);
exit(0);
}

void init(struct employee **head){
    *head = NULL;
}

int push(struct employee d, struct employee **head)
{
    int done=0;
    struct employee *s;

    s = (struct employee *)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
    if (s!=NULL)
    {
        *s = d;
        s->next = *head;  
        *head = s;
         done = 1;
    }

    return done;
}

int pop(struct employee *s, struct employee **head)
{
    int done=0;
    struct employee *temp;

    if (*head != NULL)
   {
        temp = *head;
        *s = **head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
        done = 1;
    }

    return done;
}

void show(struct employee *head)
{
    struct employee *i;
    printf("--- Top of stack  ---\n");
    for (i=head; i!=NULL; i=i->next) //maybe here edit for the odd positions
        printf("%d %s %.2f\n",i->am,i->name,i->salary);
    printf("---Bottom of stack---\n");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you are pushing data on top of the stack (thus your `data` becomes the head), **then** checking the difference in salary with the head employee. Said otherwise, you are comparing with yourself.

You might want to either check **before** pushing to the stack, or replace your `if` line with

```
if (head->salary > data.next->salary)
```

#### Note that you also want to check whether the `next` node exists before checking its salary.